# Volatile write = volatile read

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, happens-before

I have seen something like `fld = fld` a few times before but in all these cases the dummy write can be eliminated with a better performance.

```
public class Tst{
    public volatile int fld = 1;

    public void m(){
         //... Something
        fld = fld;
        //... Something else
    }
}
```

The question is if such dummy write has its use cases or this is some workaround? To me this seems to be exactly the same as (since no stores and loads can be reordered across the dummy write according to JMM)

```
public class Tst{
    public volatile int fld = 1;
    private static final Unsafe U;

    public void m(){
         //... Something
        U.fullFence();
        //... Something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Except `Unsafe` is an internal API (although nowadays you also have [`VarHandle.fullFence()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#fullFence--) as a public alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Your dummy write is broken, a volatile write is guaranteed to happen before a volatile read, in your "pattern" you're doing the opposite so reordering can happen.

`fullFence` guarantees no reordering but it's not something that should be used.